# Xamarin iOS - Interactive Swipe

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xcode, xamarin.ios

I am trying to implement a Swipe into my Xamarin iOS App like all big Names are having. I found a [simple example](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/View-Controller-Transitions) written in Swift, but I get stuck with the second code area.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController, toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return SimpleAnimationController()
    }
}
```

The problem is, that in C# a class can only inherit from one class or multiple Interfaces. Also I don't know exactly what the function ***func navigationController*** is doing.

So how can I translate the code snippet?

Thanks for your help!

**[Edit 1]**

So I implemented the class now like this:

```
public class MyFadeTransition : UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition, IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning
{
    private UIViewController TransitioningController;

    public MyFadeTransition(UIViewController transitioningController)
    {
        TransitioningController = transitioningController;
        TransitioningController.View.AddGestureRecognizer(new UIPanGestureRecognizer(DidPan));
    }

    void IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.AnimateTransition(IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning transitionContext)
    {
        var fromViewController = transitionContext.GetViewControllerForKey(UITransitionContext.FromViewControllerKey);

        var toViewController = transitionContext.GetViewControllerForKey(UITransitionContext.ToViewControllerKey);
        transitionContext.ContainerView.AddSubview(toViewController.View);

        toViewController.View.Alpha = 0.0f;

        UIView.Animate(0.35, () =>
        {
            toViewController.View.Alpha = 1.0f;
            Debug.WriteLine("Custom Transitioning");

        }, () =>
        {
            transitionContext.CompleteTransition(!transitionContext.TransitionWasCancelled);
            Debug.WriteLine("Custom Transitioning Done");

        });
    }

    double IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning.TransitionDuration(IUIViewControllerContextTransitioning transitionContext)
    {
        return 0.35;
    }

    public void DidPan(UIPanGestureRecognizer gesture)
    {
        var point = gesture.LocationInView(TransitioningController.View);
        double percent = Math.Max(Math.Min((point.X / 300), 0.99), 0.0f);

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Point: {0} | Percent: {1}", point, percent));

        switch (gesture.State)
        {
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
                // this.UsingGesture = true
                this.TransitioningController.NavigationController?.PopViewController(true);
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                UpdateInteractiveTransition((System.nfloat)percent);
                break;
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled:
                if (percent > 0.5)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Finishing Transition");
                    this.FinishInteractiveTransition();
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Cancelling Transition");
                    this.CancelInteractiveTransition();
                }
                break;
            default:
                Debug.WriteLine("Unhandled Transition state");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the ViewControllers are transitioning, but they do also if the user only swipes some pixels. Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.iOS you have an interface equivalent:

```
IUINavigationControllerDelegate
```

You can implement as many interfaces as you want.

You can find it right [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.IUINavigationControllerDelegate/#memberlist)

The Xamarin translation would be

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController, IUINavigationControllerDelegate
{

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
        NavigationController.Delegate = this;
    }

    [Export("navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:")]
    public IUIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning GetAnimationControllerForOperation(UINavigationController navigationController, UINavigationControllerOperation operation, UIViewController fromViewController, UIViewController toViewController)
    {
        return new SimpleAnimationController();
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but the line **NavigationController.Delegate = this;** throws an exception whether called in AwakeFromNib or ViewDidLoad.
**System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

**EDIT:** Funny thing: **if (this.NavigationController != null){
    NavigationController.Delegate = this;
   }** seems to do the job

Comment: That's because your ViewController doesn't have a NavigationController.
How do you start the MyViewController? Do you use the PushViewController-method? It has to be in a NavigationController's navigation stack, which only happens if you use PushViewController when showing the ViewController or if you create a new NavigationController with the new ViewController as the root ViewController.

Comment: Well there is a NavigationController attached, I can navigate through the whole app. And yes, I push the new ones. Also the written transition does work if I put it into the if statement, so maybe a bug?

Comment: If it works with the if-statement I don't think it sets the delegate, since we know that the  NavigationController is null at that point, right? Can you debug it and see if it goes into the if or just passed it?

Comment: Unfortunately due to the newest Xamarin Alpha versions three is actually no way for me to debug, but I wrote a simple **Debug.WriteLine** Line inside **AnimateTransition** and it outputs exactly what I expected. So the delegate just works. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Exactly what I am thinking, but now I am stuck on an other issue

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin What's your other issue?

Comment: Added the next issue to the Main Post